# Why is "alienated" the answer to "One caregiver in particular turned indifferent"?

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

The clue is:

> One caregiver in particular turned indifferent. (9)

I think the answer may be "alienated" but I can't really explain it. Can anyone else provide a good explanation?

Answer (score 17):

Explanation

> "One" = A
>  "caregiver" = EN (Enrolled Nurse)
>  "particular" = DETAIL (as a noun, they are synonyms)
>  "particular turned" = LIATED
>  "caregiver in particular turned" = LI(EN)ATED
>  "One caregiver in particular turned" = A+LI(EN)ATED
>  "indifferent" is then the definition

Comment: Where in the world is EN a common abbreviation?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I found a few references to this: [here](https://abbreviations.woxikon.co.nz/en/en), [here](https://www.acronymfinder.com/EN.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licensed_practical_nurse#United_Kingdom). Seems to be used in Australia, New Zealand, Canada and the UK although, I'll admit, it's a less well know acronym.

Comment: Never heard it in Canada.  We use RN for Registered Nurse.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore actually, my mistake, it seems in Canada "enrolled nurses" are referred to as "graduate nurses", see [here](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Enrolled+Nurse)

Comment: @ChrisCudmore In general, enrolled nurses are second-level nurses who work under registered nurses but are sometimes called by different names in different countries.

Comment: In the UK it's SEN (State Enrolled Nurse) or (before that) SRN (State Registered Nurse)

Comment: I'm from NZ, and Enrolled Nurse is a term I'd never come across before today